# Can I group Storybook controls using TypeScript types?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, storybook

I have some components inheriting hundreds of HTML attributes as TS prop types, so the args table of their stories are displaying too many props. I want to group the controls of those stories in order to separate the main props of the component with all those HTML ones. There's a way to automatically group all props inside the HTMLAttributes type?

Here's the way to group story controls manually https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-docs/doc-blocks#grouping